# Strange behaviour when writing to a mongo db using spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to write some data using spring data for mongodb and I encountered an interesting problem and I'm not sure why occurs.

I have the following mongo config written in scala:

```
object MongoConfig {
  val SERVER = "localhost"
  val PORT = 27017
  val DB_NAME = "test"
  val COLLECTION = "test"
}

@Configuration
class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  def getDatabaseName: String = MongoConfig.DB_NAME
  def mongo: Mongo = new MongoClient(MongoConfig.SERVER, MongoConfig.PORT)
}
```

then I have the following DAO class:

```
@Repository
class TrackDao {

  @Autowired
  private var mongoOp: MongoOperations = _

  def save(data: java.util.List[Data]) = {
    val t = new DataDto(data.asScala, "some data")
    mongoOp.save(t, MongoConfig.COLLECTION)
  }
}
```

and after I try to write something to the database from java:

```
private void write() {
   List<Data> data = // some data
   mongoDao.save(data)
}
```

the last code works, but if I try to do this:

```
private void write() {
   List<Data> data = // some data
   List<Data> data1 = data.sublist(0, 3);
   mongoDao.save(data1);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Document field names can't start with '$' (Bad Key: '$outer')
```

Also the Data java object:

```
public class Data {
   private int x;
   //
}
```

And the DataDto:

```
case class DataDto(data: Buffer[Data], label: String) {
  def getData: Buffer[Data] = data
  def getLabel: String = label
}
```

For me this is really a strange problem. Probably if all the code will be written in Java I would not have this problem, but I would like to find a solution like this.

Comment: It sounds like you're using the Scala equivalent to a Java inner class and it's using the dollar sign as part of a generated field name.

Comment: @chrylis I know that that error might appear if I'm using an inner class, but that's the thing I'm not. DataDto is not an inner class..

Comment: Are you sure the snippets you post are correct? In the not working version I would assume you are trying to save 'data1' and not 'data'.

Comment: @Gimby yeah it's data1. I corrected that. Thanks!

Comment: So basically the problem happens as soon as you try to persist a sublist. If you create a completely new arraylist and copy the three elements you want to it, everything will work as expected. Correct?

Comment: @Gimby nope I also tried that. I still have the same problem. It's really strange..